# Does the ChatGPT Image Editor plugin do cut-and-paste?

Tags: images, chatgpt

Does the [Image Editor plugin](https://gptstore.ai/plugins/imageeditor-dev) on ChatGPT do cut-and-paste editing, like cutting a bird out of one image and pasting it into another?

Comment: This is a question about a plugin for ChatGPT.

Comment: [Are questions about plugins on- or off-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5235/18147)